# How to supply dimensions of screen device in pixels (not inches)?

Tags: r, plot, screen, pixel

Why does

```
dev.new(width=1000, height=100, units="px", res=1)
dev.size("px")
```

return

```
[1] 1088  108
```

instead of

```
[1] 1000  100
```

I really would like to draw pixel-precision plots on screen. Isn't it possible?

`?dev.new` says "care is needed with the interpretation of e.g. width, and for the standard bitmap devices units = "in", res = 72 is forced if neither is supplied but both width and height are."

"if neither is supplied"... How can I supply both?

EDIT

```
windows(100, 10, xpinch=10, ypinch=10)
dev.size("px")
```

is giving me

```
[1] 1000   99
```

(!)

Comment: `windows(100, 10, xpinch=10, ypinch=10)` gives me dims of 1000 and 100 as expected with R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64.

Comment: Mine is R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on x86_64-w64-mingw32 (version.string on platform after command version). Your only difference is an extra /x64 in the end...